# Extracting raster information within/inside polygon (for each contour)

Tags: raster, grass-gis, contour, grass.script

I have raster data of NDVI and DEM
I have already created contour from DEM. Now I'm trying to find following:

for each contour find the raster information within the contour.

Can anyone suggest available methods in GRASS?

I used r.mask and then v.what.rast it works. However, I got the ndvi values of the area that has been masked (NDVI values that lie inside the polygon plus the outside area) [image -1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMNlm.jpg

Actually, I need NDVI values that lie inside the contour/polygon [image-2]  https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2YWl.jpg

I may actually need to intersect each contour with the NDVI and extract the NDVI values (inside the contour).

Comment: Please edit your question to include details of what you've tried.  Where exactly are you stuck?  What "raster information" are you trying to find?  Do you want to intersect each contour and extract the NDVI values?  Do you want to get all the unique values for each contour?  Do you want the average NDVI for each contour?  At the moment, your question will be closed because you haven't provided enough details for us to give you a good answer.

Comment: Just guessing, perhaps  v.what.rast - Uploads raster values at positions of vector points to the table (https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/v.what.rast.html) is what you need

Comment: Thanks @markusN .. I've used v.what.rast it works fine. However, I got the ndvi values of the area that has been masked (NDVI values that lie inside the polygon plus the outside area) [image -1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMNlm.jpg                                               Actually, I need NDVI values that lie inside the contour/polygon [image-2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2YWl.jpg

Comment: In this case enlarge the computation region a bit, using g.region. It also supports relative bounding box coordinates management: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/g.region.html#changing-extent-and-raster-resolution-using-values (4th + 5th example)

Comment: @markusN :I've used g.region and then v.what.rast but it uploads all values of the area. I need points that are within the polygon. [do I need to use g.region n=n+1000 w=w-500 and/or g.region n=s+1000 e=w+1000  but I don't understand it] g.region vect=contour_f_10316_10344_boundary_polygon -p                 
projection: 1 (UTM)
zone:       14
datum:      wgs84
ellipsoid:  wgs84
north:      5087624.94993913
south:      5087504.66614475
west:       688466.18147708
east:       688630.63290309
nsres:      5.01182477
ewres:      4.98337655
rows:       24
cols:       33
cells:      792

Comment: @markusN : I'm planning to use v.edit and use polygon/contour (some coordinates pairs) as a feature vector. See whether it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest having a look at either

- r.univar (https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/r.univar.html)
  where your conture map might represent the zones (has to be an
  integer map)
- r.statistics
  (https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/r.statistics.html)

In the manuals you find links to other related and probably relevant modules.